# Accessing variables from a functionally declared stack

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, stack

In creating the interface for a Stack in JavaScript - using a functional style as opposed to prototypal or pseudoclassical style, should the below "storage" and "count" variables be someInstance.storage and someInstance.count, respectively so they can be accessed on an instance of this stack later?

With the variables declared as they are now, once we create and instance of the stack by executing the function, we lose access to see what the count (size) and the storage (properties in the stack).

What's the best means of declaring properties (not methods) we need to access later using a functional creation pattern?

Thanks!

```
var Stack = function(){
  var someInstance = {};

  var storage = {};
  var count = 0;


  someInstance.push = function(value){
    storage[count++] = value;
  };

  someInstance.pop = function(){

    if(count){
      var popped = storage[--count];
    }

    delete storage[count];

    return popped;

  };

  someInstance.size = function(){
    return count;

  };

  return someInstance;
};

var stack = Stack();
```

Answer (score 1):

The private variables mentioned below can be studied in javascript of `closure`.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

```
var Stack = function(){
  // PUBLIC
  var someInstance = {};

  // PRIVATE: Attach _ to private variables. (just implicit rule.)
  var _storage = {};
  var _count = 0;


  someInstance.push = function(value){
    storage[_count++] = value;
  };

  someInstance.pop = function(){

    if(_count){
      var popped = storage[--_count];
    }

    delete storage[_count];

    return popped;

  };

  someInstance._size = function(){
    return _count;

  };

  // if you assign public variable, you can access!!!
  someInstance.size = _size;
  someInstance.count = _count;

  return someInstance;
};

var stack = Stack();
```

Comment: Technique I've used before, but forgot about. This will make shaking the programming rust off much easier :). Thanks @seunggabi!

Answer (score 1):

Whether `storage` and `count` *should* be `someInstance.storage` and `someInstance.count` depends on how you want the user of this instance to work it. That's a bit opinion based. My opinion is that a stack shouldn't allow the user to change the count with something like `someInstance.count = 10` because that would break it.

Personally I would make `count` and `storage` private which will prevent accidental bugs that could happen with direct access. A nice way to do this is to capture them in a closure and provide a getter for `count` so you can still read the count, but can't change it. Something like:

```js
var Stack = function(){ 
    let storage = [], count = 0; // these will be caputured as a closure

    return {
        // the returned object will have push, pop, and a count getter
        push(v) {
            storage.push(v)
            count++
        },
        pop() {
            if (count) count--
            return storage.pop()
        },
        get count(){      // allow reading of count
            return count
        }

    } 
}
var stack =  Stack();
stack.push("hello");
stack.push("goodby");
stack.count = 10          // has no effect

console.log(stack.count)  // count is still 2
console.log(stack.pop())

console.log(stack.count)
console.log(stack.pop())

console.log(stack.count)
```

Of course, since this mostly uses an array, you could do away with the `count` variable altogether and just use `storage.length`

Comment: BTW, why use `Object.create` to duplicate a newly created object? Just `return stack;` will suffice. Each call to `Stack` already creates a new object, why duplicate it? Nice answer nevertheless!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you're right. I originally had it as a single object outside the function to allow a single object prototype without copying the functions in each instance -- but that was too ornate.

Comment: Yeah. I was going to suggest that you wrap the whole thing in an IIFE so that the `Object.create` bit makes sense but that will get rid of the closures which are an essential thing in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add getters and setters for them in the `someInstance` object (courtesy of closures) like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(someInstance, "count", {
   get: function() {
      return count;
   },
   set: function(value) {
      count = value;
   }
});
```

You can omit the `set` part if you want to be able to just get the value and not set it.

**Example:**

```js
var Stack = function(){
  var someInstance = {};

  var storage = {};
  var count = 0;

  Object.defineProperty(someInstance, "count", {
    get: function() {
      console.log("getter called");
      return count;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      console.log("setter called");
      count = value;
    }
  });

  return someInstance;
};

var stack = Stack();

console.log(stack.count);
stack.count = 55;
console.log(stack.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Stack = function(){ 
    let storage = [], count = 0; // these will be caputured as a closure

    return {
        // the returned object will have push, pop, and a count getter
        push(v) {  //method
            storage.push(v)
            count++
        },
        pop: function() {
            if (count) count--
            return storage.pop()
        },
        get count(){      // allow reading of count
            return count
        },
  get insidebox(){      // allow reading of count
            return storage
        },
  callprice:function(cnt){   
  var price=cnt*100;
  return price;
  }

    } 
}


Stack.prototype.price2 = function() {
    return "testpr";
};

var sb =  Stack();
console.log(sb.count);
sb.push('paint');
console.log(sb.insidebox);
console.log(sb.count); 
sb.push('Sharee');
console.log(sb.insidebox);
sb.push('Shirt'); 
sb.push('shoes');
console.log(sb.insidebox);
sb.pop();
console.log(sb.insidebox);
console.log(sb.count);
console.log(sb.callprice(sb.count));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

Person.prototype.nationlity='Indian';

Person.prototype.fullname = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
};

var myFather = new Person("Lalji", "Maurya", 50, "blue");
console.log(myFather.fullname());
console.log(myFather); 
console.log(myFather.nationlity); 

var myBrother = new Person("Ashish", "Maurya", 28, "black");
console.log(myBrother.fullname());
console.log(myBrother); 
console.log(myBrother.nationlity);
```